# Rails check application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have rails3 application and want to check it every few hours (cron)
verify database connection, free disk space ,etc... 
What else should I check ?
Also is there a special gem for creating some kind of test controller with all I need, or shoul I create it myself?

Comment: how are you planning to verify a database connection?

Comment: I don't know now..Do you have ideas?

Comment: Maybe I need to call recconect! method for ActiveRecord::Base.connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than try and build your own analysis tools, you should try and use what rails provides you.

http://rails-analyzer.rubyforge.org/pl_analyze/

http://rails-analyzer.rubyforge.org/tools/

Although new relic is the best web based monitoring tool for rails you could try some alternatives.

http://drewblas.com/2008/05/29/comparison-of-rails-monitoring-apps/

Comment: Thanks but I need something like a webservice with current application state